# Adding column to left hand side of table - Python docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I have searched high and low (on various forums) and simply can't find the answer. I have a table in a docx file and would like to use the docx Python module to modify it.
I need to add a column to the left side of the table. According to the documentation, using the add_column() function adds a column to the right side of the table.
I have also tried changing the directionality of the table to a RTL table with the following code:

```
import docx
from docx.enum.table import WD_TABLE_DIRECTION

file = test.docx
doc = docx.Document(file)
tbls = doc.tables #this gives me 3 tables in a list of table objects
test = tbls[1]
test.table_direction = WD_TABLE_DIRECTION.RTL
test.add_column(1)
doc.save(file)
```

Upon opening the resulting file, I found that the code still adds a column only to the left side.
Does someone know how to add a column to the right side of a table?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try LTR,  and also use Inches to define the column width so that the added column can be displayed correctly.

```
import docx
from docx.enum.table import WD_TABLE_DIRECTION
from docx.shared import Cm, Inches

file = 'test.docx'
doc = docx.Document(file)
tbls = doc.tables 
test = tbls[1]
test.table_direction = WD_TABLE_DIRECTION.LTR
test.add_column(Inches(1.0))
doc.save(file)
```